# paired linear model in R

Tags: r, lm, limma

I am looking for a method to use pairing information in my lm model. My model compares Cancer-Normal for paired samples.

```
value
1.21 2.3 2.2 3.1 1.2 0.12

group
"Cancer" "Normal" "Cancer" "Normal" "Cancer" "Normal"

pairs
001 001 002 002 003 003
```

My model:

```
summary(lm(value ~ group-1))
```

Comment: Use a linear mixed effects model. Also, don't remove the intercept (there are theoretical considerations why you shouldn't do that and you'll need the intercept in the mixed effects model, e.g., something like `library(lmerTest); lmer(value ~ group + (1 | pairs), data = DF)`).

Comment: I did lmer and got one p-value for (Intercept) and one for groupNormal.

Comment: Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           2.3112     0.5521 40.6000   4.186 0.000148 ***
groupNormal  -1.8665     0.7418 20.2000  -2.516 0.020417 *

Comment: OK? That's just the usual treatment contrasts. The intercept is the default "base level", i.e., here the cancer group mean (this could be changed by `relevel`ing the group variable) and `groupNormal` is the difference of the normal group mean to the intercept.